# What is the difference between the characters of 问 and 何？

Tags: simplified-characters

I am really having a difficult time trying to understand what these two characters mean. I know the second character means what but I don't know what the first character means.

Comment: It's possible to look up [问](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=问) ("to ask") and [何](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=何) ("what / how / why / which / carry") in a dictionary.  Is this the kind of answer you're after?  If there's something else you specifically wish to know, please [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are very different.

问：动词或者名词 meaning: ask or question

You can say:
我问你:

何: 通常不单独使用。可以有：为何、何时、何地等，都是“什么”的意思。

You can say:
昨天你为何没有回家呢？

Comment: 谢谢！Thank you for this